# Setting Multiple Attribute as Class Attribure in Weka Java API for MLP Model

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, multiclass-classification, mlp

I'm working on single-label multi-class classification task using weka API. I want to train one Multilayer Perceptron model to predict the class percentage values for each class by generating one-hot encoded columns from my class attribute column.

In the examples on the Internet, after generating an Instances object in the Weka Java API, only one attribute is selected as a class attribute.

On the examples:

Data upload

```java
Instances data = ...
```

Selecting the last attribute as a class attribute

```java
data.setClassIndex (data.numAttributes () - 1);
```

What I'm looking for:

Selecting multiple attributes as a class attribute

```java
Instances data = ...
data.setClassIndex (1,2,5,6,...);
```

How can I do that?